# how to convert UTC timezone into UK time zone("European/london")

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println( f.format(new Date()));
```

This will be in UTC timezone , i need to set in UK(European/london) timezone.?

Comment: This answer to a previous question might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540295/15310387

Answer (score 0):

Stop using the legacy `java.util.Date` class and use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead.

```
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
    System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
```

Outputs: `2021-05-04T07:15:22.2556157+01:00[Europe/London]`

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z");
OffsetDateTime dateTimeLondon = dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toOffsetDateTime();

System.out.println(formatter.format(dateTimeLondon));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need London timezone, it would be replace UTC with time zone you need in the getTimeZOne method.

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(f.format(GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is various way to do it. but in your question, You want specifically for European/London. **TimeZone** will give you a facility to do this.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdF= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
sdF.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(sdF.format(new Date()));
```